# PouchDB sync not sending credentials to CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I have a secured CouchDB instance running. For Replication, I was following the instructions on the "Getting Started" guide. However PouchDB doens't seem to send my credentials to the server so I'm getting an "Authentication required" error from CouchDB.

#### Reproduce

```
this.db = new PouchDB('nfcs');    
this.remote = 'https://USER:PASSWORD@couchdb.pixelarbeit.de/nfcs';

let options = {
    live: true,
    retry: true,
    continuous: true
};

this.db.sync(this.remote, options)
    .on('error', err => console.log('PouchDB Error NFCs', err))
    .on('active', err => console.log('PouchDB Active', err))
    .on('complete', err => console.log('PouchDB Complete', err));
```

**Headers sent to server**

```
Request URL:https://couchdb.pixelarbeit.de/nfcs/
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
Remote Address:185.26.156.40:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers

Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:8100
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Cache-Control, Content-Type, Server
Cache-Control:must-revalidate
Connection:close
Content-Length:61
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 16 Oct 2017 06:12:45 GMT
Server:CouchDB/1.6.1 (Erlang OTP/17)
WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="server"
Request Headers

Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,ru;q=0.2,es;q=0.2
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:couchdb.pixelarbeit.de
Origin:http://localhost:8100
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:8100/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Why are you setting `remote` manually, rather than the normal way of `db = new PouchDB("https://USER:PASSWORD@couchdb.pixelarbeit.de/nfcs");`?

Comment: I used it this way before, but since it wasn't sending credentials I thought it may be part of the problem. I found it like this in the "Getting Started" guide, so I tried it this way.

Answer (score -2):

I just fixed the issue. It seems like a PouchDB plugin broke the functionality.